# How to stop Lubuntu 16.04 touchpad switching desktops?

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, powerpc

I have recently installed Lubuntu Deasktop on my PowerBook G4. It was previously running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 but Lubuntu is much more responsive on this older, slower machine. One problem that Lubuntu has introduced is that when I move the cursor with the touchpad, it sometimes makes the desktop switch between Desktop 1 and Desktop 2. This is annoying. I found a solution for older versions of Lubuntu but not for 16.04. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you use the alternate desktops?  If you don't there is a simple solution.

Comment: I have just changed it to single desktop! I would still like to know how to fix this though...

Answer (score 0):

Are you touching the scroll wheel when you move the cursor? Moving this while on the desktop will have this effect.

Comment: I am  using a touchpad so it doesn't have a scroll wheel but yes, it happens when I am doing 2 finger scrolling.